# RoR: Add a blank field to a simple_fields_for loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, for-loop, field

I am sure this is a silly question, but I have been searching for some time now without finding an answer.

I have a nested form using simple_forms.  I get all the child objects successfully with

```
 = f.simple_fields_for :fund_levels do |fl|
     = fl.input :title
     = fl.input :description
     = fl.input :maxnumber
     = fl.input :price
```

This gets all existing fund_levels.  However, I also want to add a blank set at the end of the list.  So that if there are no existing fund_levels, it simply shows a blank "subform", if there are two existing fund_levels, it will show those two plus a blank "subform".

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build it in your controller:

```
@object.fund_levels.build
```

where `@object` is the object being passed to `form_for`.

Comment: I put this into the edit section of my controller and that seemed to do the trick.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple conditional in the view to check if there are any `fund_levels` and show a form to add a new one conditionally

```
- unless @fund_levels.any?
  = f.simple_fields_for @fund_levels.build do |f|
    = f.input :title
    = f.input :description
    = f.input :maxnumber
    = f.input :price
```

Comment: Ok, thanks!  Seems simple enough.  However, what would I need to do on the parent model side for this to work?  It would have to recognize new_fund_level as a fund_level_attribute or it wouldn't post it correctly (just testing quickly it returned a can't mass assign protected attributes: new_fund_level.

Comment: Sorry I meant `new_fund_level` to just be an instance variable that you could set in your controller. Or call `build` on an existing fund_levels object. You shouldn't have to do anything on the model in this case.